# Maple plotting and loops

Tags: maple

I need to plot all of the curves generated using a Maple *for loop*. As an example, consider the simple loop:

```
For j from 1 by 1 to 10
    do
        plot({[f(x,j),g(x,j), x=x_min..x_max]}, options)
    end do;
```

I need to plot all of the curves so generated under one set of axes. What I have here seems to plot only one curve, corresponding to the value j=10.

Comment: Use **plots[display]** (see the Maple help).

Comment: I can't find anything about loops and plotting. Can you use my example above to explain. That would be beneficial to me.

Comment: Search for _Taylor_ [here](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=plots%2Fdisplay) as an example. If you want to use the **for** loop instead of **seq**, accumulate a **list** of plots inside the loop and then **display** the list.

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to use a **for** loop to do this, it is neither preferable nor Maple-ish. It is much better to use Maple's looping operator, **seq**.

plot([seq([f(x,j), g(x,j), x= x_min..x_max], j= 1..10)]);

If you have multiple plots generated with various plotting commands, you can combine them on the same set of axes with **display**.

A:= plot(...):
B:= plot(...):
plots:-display([A,B]);

or simply

plots:-display([plot(...), plot(...)]);

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. Let me extend my initial question a bit. Suppose that we have two such "sequences" of plots, and we want to plot them concurrently. For example, plot seq([f(x,j),g(x,j),x=x_min..x_max],j=1..10) and seq([p(x,j),q(x,j),x=x_min..x_max],j=1..10) on the same set of axes. How would you modify your suggestion above to do this task?

Comment: Okay, I expanded the answer to fulfill the request in your comment.